# Get SPListItem using stored procedure

Tags: sharepoint, stored-procedures, splistitem

Is it possible to get list items using stored procedure in sql server?
Everybody can give me any advices to solve that way...
I'm very please if you can give me a stored procedure code can do that,

And...is it more effective than another way, such as Rest Service...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking it is possible, but practically it makes hardly any sense and is highly discouraged. Reasons why *not* to try fetching `SPListItem`s directly from the SQL database:

- **Legal** — the SQL-level data structures and related stored procedures represent Microsoft's intellectual property and even though being officially [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339475%28v=office.12%29.aspx) as part of [Microsoft Open Specifications](http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/default.aspx), using them requires [licensing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346586.aspx) thereof and paying royalties.
- **Architectural** — it's against SharePoint's architecture and overcoming SharePoint's own data access APIs may result in unexpected behavior.
- **Maintenance** — there's no guarantee the SQL structures remain the same / compatible across versions whatsoever.
- **Portability** — just say good bye to SharePoint Online (Office 365) compatibility.
- **Security** — you are effectively bypassing SharePoint's permission checks and security architecture.
- **Governance** — no sane SharePoint admin will *ever* let you access SharePoint's SQL storage directly from a custom (non-Microsoft) code.

The result: **don't do it**, unless you are in a very specific scenario (e.g. developing complex a migration tool, but I doubt you would be asking such a beginner's question on SO in that case). Speculating about performance is hence irrelevant.

Comment: You are welcome. If it helps, you should accept it. Not meaning I can't live without that, but you are new here and that's the way SO works: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Thanks for your answer...! My boss required me to find some way to get an item to make reporting...(that's my understand ^^), and he advises me to find something about stored procedue, Rest Service,...afther that find what is the best way to do. But i'm a beginer in sharepoint, and need any-help to give him (my boss) an answer...:)

Comment: For the sake of reporting have a look at SQL Server Reporting Services. SharePoint works with them and you can report about SharePoint contents in Reporting Services.